# Binary tree insertion sort in C

Tags: c, data-structures, recursion, tree, binary-tree

Hey can anyone explain how to sort a binary tree using insertion sort in C language where time complexity is an issue. I am just learning to code. Thank you guys!

Comment: How can a binary tree be out of order!?

Comment: if you just started learning to code, try some other data structures first, before binary trees!

Comment: @StoryTeller, gave you an up vote. As he stated, he is just learning so he may not be familar with traversal of the trees.

Comment: @VenomFangs, I was really curious :) Thought I may learn something new

Comment: Thanks guys that was all the encouragement I needed to take my coding skills seriously. :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you coded the binary tree in the traditional sense, then when you add items to the tree, it will preserve the sorted order. You can get the full list of items in order by traversing the tree. I would recommend you read:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree

Also take a look at: http://nova.umuc.edu/~jarc/idsv/lesson1.html

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that there's a certain terminology to use here. A *binary tree* is a data structure where every node has at most two children. There are no conventions for ordering of nodes in a binary tree.

A *binary search tree* is a binary tree such that for given a node N all nodes in the left subtree of N are considered "less than" N and all nodes in the right subtree of N are considered "greater than" N. You could also let nodes considered "equal to" N in the tree, as long as you consistently define them to be put in the left subtree or right subtree.

As others have suggested, your best best is either to amend the code to construct a binary search tree instead of a normal binary tree, or convert the binary tree into a linear data structure and sort it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#define FIN "algsort.in"
#define FOUT "algsort.out"

struct Node {
   int val;
   struct Node *left;
   struct Node *right;
};

typedef struct Node node;

void insert(node **bt, node *Node) {

if( !(*bt) ) {

     *bt = Node;

} else {

        if( Node->val < (*bt)->val )

            insert(&((*bt)->left), Node);

        else

            insert(&((*bt)->right), Node);
 }
 }

 void printout(struct Node *node) {

   if(node->left) printout(node->left); 

   printf("%d ", node->val);  

   if(node->right) printout(node->right);
 }

 void postorder(struct Node *node) {

      if(node->left) printout(node->left);   

      if(node->right) printout(node->right); 

      printf("%d ", node->val);  
 }

 int main () {

     int i, n, elem;    

     node *curr; 

     freopen(FIN, "r", stdin);

     freopen(FOUT, "w", stdout);

     node *bt = NULL;

     scanf("%d", &n);

     for(i = 0; i < n; ++i) {

        scanf("%d", &elem); 

        curr = malloc( sizeof(struct Node) );

        curr->val = elem;

        curr->left = NULL;

        curr->right = NULL;

        insert(&bt, curr );

     }

    printout( bt ); 

    return(0);
  }
```

Let's say that algsort.in contains the following array of integers:

algsort.int -> 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,0,1,-1;

algsort.out -> -1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9